# Schaum explication of eigenvectors of Lz

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, operators

In Schaum's Quantum Mechanics, in Chapter 6 Angular Momentum,
they say  "the eigenvectors of $L^2$ and $L_z$ are functions that
depend on the angles $\theta$ and $\phi$ only;  hence, we can
represent the wavefunction as $\psi(r,\theta,\phi) = R(r)Y^m_l(\theta,
\phi)$"

Is it not true that if you a full set of eigenvectors for an
operator, in this case $L_z$, then you have a basis for the
eigenspace of $L_z$?  But then the eigenspace of $L_z$ isn't all
possible wavefunctions?  Because the wavefunction has a radial element
$R(r)$?  I guess I'm just confused about the difference between
the  "space spanned by the eigenvectors of $L_z$"  and the full
set of all possible wavefunctions for a particle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an observable, that is like a symmetric matrix. So its eigenvectors span the whole space so you can form a basis for the whole space. So the span of the eigenvectors really is the whole space. What about eigenspaces?

You did have to use all the eigenvectors to get the whole space, not just ones that share the same eigenvalue. If you only use ones with the same eigenvalue their span will only be the eigenspace not the whole space.

So that's eigenspaces (span of eigenvectors with same eigenvalue) versus the whole space (span of eigenvectors with all possible eigenvalue). But we need to talk about products with functions of $r$.

Now, that just means that you can multiply any $R(r)$ by an eigenfunction of $L_z$ and you will get another eigenfunction of $L_z$ with the same eigenvalue. So by taking radial basis vectors you can take a linearly independent set of them and multiply them by an eigenfunction of $L_z$ and you will get another eigenfunction of $L_z$ with the same eigenvalue this time linearly independent. Do the same for a linearly independent set of eigenfunctions that is as big as possible and you get your basis for the whole space.

All these products with $R(r)$ just live in the $L_z$ eigenspace, it's a big eigenspace.

Comment: That is an interesting point about how it's true that just considering the fact that an observable is a symmetric matrix that we already know that its eigenvectors span the whole space.

Comment: I think I understand it, thanks to your explanation.  I am thinking of it this way:   Just for the example where l=4, m=+2, and we have a central potential.  Then I visualize the eigenfunctions of this particle, i.e.the possible wave functions this particle could have, as being the following set:   Consider a wave function where if you pick any value of r, and just look at the spherical shell portion of that function at that r, you see that the spherical shell is this particular  "tortoise shell"  pattern depicted

Comment: on  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics  (that nice picture under Laplace's Spherical Harmonics of the spinning balls).  However, as you look at the shells that pop out for various values of r, you find that each tortoise shell pattern is  "tinged"  a particular color as if viewed on a monochrome computer monitor.  For example, at r=3 it might be all tinged blue, at r=5 it might be all tinged green.  Now conceive that blue corresponds to some constant real number that is the scaling of the tortoiseshell value, green to another constant real number, and so on for any

Comment: color / any real number.  For example, so now we find that for r=3, the blue tortoise shell would have the formula  50 sin 2$\theta$ cos 2$\phi$  because the scalar corresponding to blue is 50.  Then at r=5 the tortoise shell would have the formula 44 sin 2$\theta$ cos 2$\phi$, and say at r=.001 the tortoise shell would have the formula -7 sin 2$\theta$ cos 2$\phi$ corresponding to pink, and so on.  (The $\theta \phi$ portion of the formula is most likely not accurate.)

Comment: So my point is that if you consider the set of all possible distributions of colors that could be assigned to these functions, but holding to the fact that at all spherical shells the tortoise shell pattern corresponding to l=4 m=+2 is preserved, that is the full set of wave functions the particle could have for this particular system with a central potential and with l=4 m=+2.  (For a non-central potential it would be less beautiful a pattern, and also I didn't take normalization of the wave function into account.)

Comment: @user4127427 To take normalization into account you just need normalized $\int R(r)r°2dr$<$\infty$ functions in the radial direction and there is another technicality that you can't consider every possible such function for a fixed l but a maximal number of independent normalizable ones suffice.

Comment: I don't quite understand but thank you for the extra detail.  I believe you are saying that only certain types of radial functions R(r) would produce a normalizable wave function.  Your other remark seems to be you are saying that when constructing a basis for generating all possible legal radial functions in this situation, you only need to look at a certain number as looking at all possible radial functions would be intractable (?)  You don't need to respond to this comment if you are busy as I will think upon your notes further.